# Restoring only structure/schema from .bak file in SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore, sql-server-2012-express

Please assist me, how to restore `.bak` file in SQL Server 2012 Express with a size of more than 10GB.

Checked on google, found third party tool idera sql safe, through which we can restore part of the `.bak` file, i.e. only schema /structure, but don't know how to use this tool to do this task.

Please assist if anyone restored `.bak` file of more than 10gb, or tried to restored only schema/structure from it.

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Server 2012 **Express** - because of the 10 GB limit ?

Comment: Assuming you have access to the database, you can right click on the database in SSMS, go to `Tasks`, and then select `Generate Scripts...`. You can script the database and all of its objects.

Comment: @Jason..i dont have db acess now...i hv only .bak file

Comment: @marc_s yes sql server 2011 exp edition

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4664/copy-a-sql-server-database-with-just-the-objects-and-no-data/

Comment: SQL 2016 developer edition is free and will be able to restore a 10G database. If this is for development purposes you can use that.

Comment: doesn't seem like  you can do that with  `.bak` files without either doing a full restore or using a tool like Apex Diff https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/create-a-database-script-from-a-backup-without-restoring-it/